# Making a Frame return results

Tags: wxpython

I seen dialogs returning results:

`if some_dlg.ShowModal() = wx.OK`

I want a similar behavior for my **frames**.

---

I want the frame to ask for options (text fields and others), with a OK and Cancel. I then want to know the results of the operation (values of the fields and which button was clicked).

Comment: Hmm, there happens to be this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/comp.lang.python/YJGd1vVNYr8/x4soJWv-ozIJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want a frame to behave like a dialog? You should just use a dialog if that's what you need. Anyway, the easiest way to do this is to use PubSub. Have the OK button handler send a different message than the Cancel button's handler. You can read this [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/) to find out how it works or read this wxPython [wiki page](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub).